# PCAP Ethertype Return

Tags: c, linux, pcap, tcpdump

I am attempting to identify the ether type of a packet that I am receiving. The ether type ID is 608 and has no corresponding definition in Ethertype.h(libpcap 1.2.1). The majority of the packets received have an either type of 8 which again has no corresponding definition in Ethertype.h. Does anyone have any ideas of what the cause may be behind this or should I contact TCPDump with an error report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the return value of `pcap_datalink()` on the `pcap_t` on which you're capturing?

If it's not `DLT_EN10MB` (which has the value 1), your packets aren't Ethernet packets, and you shouldn't parse them as Ethernet packets.

If it is `DLT_EN10MB`, then is that hex 608 or decimal 608?  If it's decimal 608, it's a length field rather than a type field.  The same applies to 8, which is the same decimal or hex and would thus be a length value rather than a type value.

Comment: The file handler for the capture device does return a 1 when I run the check through pcap_datalink.


As far as the rest of the data I found they are all in HEX.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, turns out I needed to use ntohs() on the ethertype.

Answer (score 0):

From manpage:

"The ntohs() function converts the unsigned short integer netshort from network byte order to host byte order.".

From my code:

if(ntohs(ethernet->ether_type)==0x0800) ...